# Way to use a native editor for textarea (or JS-powered WYSIWYG editor)?

Tags: tinymce, textarea, browser-extension, background-service

I'm looking for a way to use my favorite "native" editor, Sublime Text 2, to fill textareas and/or WYSIWYG-editors like TinyMCE.

I'd like to have some kind of daemon, service or browser extension that waits for, say, a focus event on a textarea and opens a new Sublime Text 2 window for me to type in. Everytime I save (could be to a file in a temporary directory for all I care), the background daemon/service/extension/… updates the contents of the web form field.

So much for my ideal scenario. Is there any way you know of to make this possible (FYI, I'm working under OS X Lion)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what browser you're using, but there's an extension for **Firefox** called "[It's all text](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/its-all-text/)" where you can:

> Right click on a textarea, select "It's All Text!" and edit the text in the editor of your choice.

You can also make a shortcut instead of rightclicking.

[EDIT] And for **Google Chrome** now there is: https://github.com/Cacodaimon/GhostTextForSublimeText

*P.S. In an ideal world all textareas should be small ST2 windows...*

Answer (score -1):

Sure, this is possible.

You'll need to write a browser extension for it.

Look for a snippet saving addon on whichever browser you use, go through the source code, figure out how it works, then make one to fit your use-case.

In the meantime, repeat: `Ctrl+C`, `Alt-Tab`, `Ctrl-V`!

Comment: While I appreciate your quick response, and thank you by the way, I don't see any reason for you to get sassy.